# AngularJS - preloader for ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using the infinite scroll technique in conjunction with `ng-repeat`. I want to display a preloader up until the directive has finished adding the items to the DOM. What would be the simplest way of achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [live DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xicemu/2/edit?html,js,output) I set up for reference.

It depends on your infinite scroll implementation. And for best answer you should set up a plunker or jsbin.

But what about just setting a loader and using `ng-if` directive to only show it while the item container is empty ?

Imagine we have a template like

```
<div id="data-container" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
    <img ng-if="!items.length" ng-src="http://placehold.it/100x395&text=Loading">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.id}}</div>
    <img ng-if="items.length && busy" ng-src="http://placehold.it/85x50&text=Loading">
</div>
```

Here `when-scrolled` is our infinite-scroll directive which just monitors the scroll position and calls the supplied handler when it is time to load more items.

```
app.directive('whenScrolled', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {  
    var containerNode = element[0];
    element.bind('scroll', function() {
      if (containerNode.scrollTop + containerNode.offsetHeight >= containerNode.scrollHeight) {
        scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Handler is called when the scroll hits the bottom of the content area.

`loadMore()` method in the controller could be defined like this:

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.busy = false;

$scope.loadMore = function() {
  if (true === $scope.busy) {
    return;
  }
  $scope.busy = true;
  $timeout(function() {
    var currentLength = $scope.items.length;
    for (var i = currentLength; i < currentLength + 10; i++) {
      $scope.items.push({id: i + 1});
    }
    $scope.busy = false;
  }, 350); // Imitating the long remote request.
};
```

We first initialize the `$scope.items` and while it's length is 0 the loading image is shown in the template as it is shown while `"!items.length"` is true. When the first items are added to the collection preloader gets hidden.

Then there's a local loading image which could be replaced with a spinner or whatever you like. It is shown then the `$scope.busy` var is set to `true` and is hidden when it's `false`. We change the `$scope.busy` value at the start and end of the aync request. Timeouts are used here for simple of  async request demo.